# ratchet HttpServer class not found

Tags: php, websocket, composer-php, ratchet

So i made a real-time chat on windows in php with websockets and every thing worked perfectly but now when i try to run the server on my vps(debian) i get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Ratchet\http\HttpServer' not found in /react-chat/bin/server.php on line 11
```

so when i look at my server.php file :

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Chat\Chat;

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

$server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat)), 2000);

$server->run();
```

every thing seems normal this is my composer.json file

```
{
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "~0.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Chat\\": "bin/src/"
        }
    }
}
```

the only warning i got when doing composer install was following 
[image: Composer install]

but i dont that warning is making the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP namespaces are case sensitive, so try `Http` instead of `http`:

```
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
```

Answer (score 2):

Strange, there is no Http directory in my src/Ratchet directory. I have downloaded the sources from http://socketo.me/ and strictly followed the instructions but this directory is simply missing.

Comment: I have the same problem